# access UIBarBarItem button inside tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created two UIBarButtonItem buttons inside viewDidLoad to be grouped on the right side of the navigation bar so that when certain condition is satisfied, one will be enabled and the other disabled and vice versa.

the buttons work fine except recognizing the condition and being enabled and disabled based on the condition.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var btnDone: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        barButtonSystemItem: .Done,
        target: self,
        action: "btnDoneFunction")
    btnDone.style = UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done
    let btnAdd: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        barButtonSystemItem: .Add,
        target: self,
        action: "btnAddFunction")
    var buttons = [btnAdd, btnDone]
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons
    if checked.count >= 1 {
        btnDone.enabled = true
        btnAdd.enabled = false
    } else {
        btnDone.enabled = false
        btnAdd.enabled = true
    }
}
```

checked is an array that holds row number of checked rows in the table inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

I tried moving the condition part:

```
 if checked.count >= 1 {
        btnDone.enabled = true
        btnAdd.enabled = false
    } else {
        btnDone.enabled = false
        btnAdd.enabled = true
    }
```

inside of didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but i can not access the buttons there.

Is there any way I can implement this? I just want to check if there are any rows checked in the table and disable the 'Add' button and enable the 'Done' button. If no row is checked, the reverse.

This is inside a UITableViewController class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the buttons in viewDidLoad so the scope of the variable is just for that function, you need to declare it inside the class.

```
class myClass{

    lazy var btnDone:UIBarButtonItem = {
        var done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
                  barButtonSystemItem: .Done,
                  target: self,
                  action: "btnDoneFunction")  
        return done      
    }()

    func anotherFunc(){
        if checked.count >= 1 {
        btnDone?.enabled = true
        } else {
            btnDone?.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

I create a generic example above that declares a btnDone as a class variable with lazy initialization, that means it will be create just as need

Comment: That enabled me to access the buttons where I want (inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath) but now when I run it and when I go to that view i get the error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
the error is at the (btnAdd! = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add,
            target: self,
            action: "btnAddCustomFunction ) inside the viewDidLoad

Comment: Add a ? instead a ! when you calling the btnDone (btnDone?.enabled = true)

Comment: @tew I just create it using lazy initialization that is actually the best optoin for what you are trying to do. Good luck with your app!

Comment: now the error happens at var buttons = [btnDone, btnAdd]
I tried your suggestion and it still happens. I tried using one of the buttons only using self.navigatioBarItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnDone like@Icaro. and it all works fine.  
I tried avoiding the first line and directly use self.navigationBar.rightBarButtonItems = [btnDone, btnAdd] with both combinations of '!' and '?' and same error.
seems like it is tied with 'rightBarButtonItems'

Comment: The lazy initialization suggested by @Icaro worked. Thank you.

Comment: @tew Great news! It is also the best approach you could take for this situation.